# How do I attach data to custom fields on INTranCost during release of POReceiptEntry?

Tags: acumatica

I need to attach custom data into new fields added to INTranCost when the PO Receipt occurs.

[image: Breadcrumbs]

Following the breadcrumbs, it seems that POReceiptEntry -> Release Action eventually calls INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc that eventually creates INTranCost.  I tried extending both POReceiptEntry and INDocumentRelease to add an event for INTranCost_RowInserted to publish a PXTrace message, but the trace doesn't appear, telling me that I'm not hitting the event that I expected.  (Which explains why the real business logic I need included didn't fire.)

```
protected virtual void _(Events.RowInserted<INTranCost> e)
{
    PXTrace.WriteInformation("This is it!");
}
```

Of course, I want to put real code in this spot, but I am just trying to make sure I'm hitting the event properly.  This works on pretty much everything else I've done, including attaching similar data to INTranExt fields.  I cannot get it to work for INTranCost so that I can add to INTranCostExt.  At this point, I can't determine if it is location (which graph extension) or a special methodology required for this special case.

I also tried overriding events and putting a breakpoint on the code, but it's like I'm not even on the same process.  (Yes, I checked that I am connected to the right Acumatica instance and that I have no errors.)

What event in which graph is required to capture the creation in INTranCost for a PO Receipt to update custom fields in INTranCostExt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Request Profiler, I was able to determine that I was close but not deep enough.  While the INTranCost object to insert was built in INDocumentRelease FILE, the actual insert was processed in INReleaseProcess graph in that same file.

[image: Stack Trace]

I only need to execute this "push" from the data captured on the POLine when the INTranCost record is created, and LineNbr is a key field and therefore never updated after it is set.  I need to be sure that I have enough data to make the connection back, and the primary key links me back to the INTran easily.  That subsequently gets back to the POReceiptLine to the POLine where the data is maintained that needs the "current value" to be captured when the transaction is posted.  Since I need to update the DAC Extension, I need to use an event that will allow an existing DAC.Update to apply my values.  Therefore, I added an event handler on INTranCost_LineNbr_FieldUpdated since that value should not be "updated" after it is set initially.

Code that accomplished the task:

```
public class INReleaseProcess_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INReleaseProcess>
{ 
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<INTranCost.lineNbr> e)
    {
        INTranCost row = (INTranCost) e.Row;

        INTran tran = PXSelect<INTran,
            Where<INTran.docType, Equal<Required<INTran.docType>>,
                And<INTran.refNbr, Equal<Required<INTran.refNbr>>,
                And<INTran.lineNbr, Equal<Required<INTran.lineNbr>>
            >>>>
            .SelectSingleBound(Base, null, row.DocType, row.RefNbr, (int?) e.NewValue);

        if (tran?.POReceiptType != null && tran?.POReceiptNbr != null)
        {
            PXResultset<POReceiptLine> Results = PXSelectJoin<POReceiptLine,
                InnerJoin<POLine, On<POLine.orderType, Equal<POReceiptLine.pOType>,
                    And<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<POReceiptLine.pONbr>,
                    And<POLine.lineNbr, Equal<POReceiptLine.pOLineNbr>>>>,
                InnerJoin<POOrder, On<POOrder.orderType, Equal<POLine.orderType>,
                    And<POOrder.orderNbr, Equal<POLine.orderNbr>>>>>,
                Where<POReceiptLine.receiptType, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.receiptType>>,
                And<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr>>,
                And<POReceiptLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.lineNbr>>>>>>.
                        SelectSingleBound(Base, null, tran.POReceiptType, tran.POReceiptNbr, tran.POReceiptLineNbr);

            if (Results != null)
            {
                foreach (PXResult<POReceiptLine, POLine, POOrder> result in Results)
                {
                    POReceiptLine receipt = result;
                    POLine line = result;
                    POOrder order = result;
                    POLineExt pOLineExt = PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(line);
                    INTranCostExt iNTranCostExt = PXCache<INTranCost>.GetExtension<INTranCostExt>(row);
                    if (pOLineExt != null && iNTranCostExt != null)
                    {
                        Base.Caches[typeof(INTranCost)].SetValueExt<INTranCostExt.usrField>(row, pOLineExt.UsrField);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```